# Execute command and compare it in a if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, command

I am using bash scripting to check whether two specific directories are containing some specific number of files. lets assume 20. Is it possible to check it in a line inside a if statement?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ [ls /path/to/dir1 | wc -l ] != 20 ||  [ ls /path/to/dir2 | wc -l ] != 50 ]; then
  echo "do this!"
elif
  echo "do that!"
fi
```

Comment: Why does the second test use `50` instead of `20`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect:

```
if [[ $(ls /path/to/dir1 | wc -l)  != 20 || $(ls /path/to/dir2 | wc -l) != 50 ]] 
then
    echo "do this!"
else
    echo "do that!"
fi
```

(I move the position of the `then` for readability)

With two square brackets `[[` you can use `||` for "or" instead of `-o`, which is closer to conventional languages.  Strictly speaking the `[[` does *pattern matching*, so although the code above will work, an arithmetic test should really use `((`:

```
if (( $(ls /path/to/dir1 | wc -l)  != 20 || $(ls /path/to/dir2 | wc -l) != 50 ))
then
    echo "do this!"
else
    echo "do that!"
fi
```

The `$( )` runs a subshell and captures the output.

Answer (score 2):

Correct `if` syntax:

`if [ $(ls /path/to/dir1 | wc -l) -ne 20 -o $(ls /path/to/dir2 | wc -l) -ne 50 ]`

But in your example you shouldn't use just `elif`. Use either `else`, or specify condition for `elif`, exmpl:

```
if [ $(ls /path/to/dir1 | wc -l) -ne 20 -o $(ls /path/to/dir2 | wc -l) -ne 50 ]
then
    echo "Do smth"
elif [ $(ls /path/to/dir3 | wc -l) -ne 100 ]
then
    echo "Do anything else"
fi
```